# How to get rid of strange characters from SQL script or from .xtxt file?

Tags: sql, character, vertica, dbeaver

How can I get rid of this kind of characters: `"¬ÃÄÃÄ¾ÄâÃ¢â"` from SQL script in DBeaver or from .txt file ?

Answer (score 0):

Found a better solution than the first:

I left the first expression as before.

It works for Latin characters, but not for Cyrillic or Greek ones, let alone other alphabets ..

The second expression says "Replace anything that is not between octal 000 and octal 177 (that's the ASCII range), with nothing.

```
WITH
indata(s) AS (
          SELECT 'Z¬ÃÄÃÄ¾ÄâÃ¢âA'
)
SELECT
  REGEXP_REPLACE(s,'['||CHR(128)||'-'||CHR(255)||']','') AS just_ascii_single_byte
, REGEXP_REPLACE(s,'[^\000-\177]','') AS nothing_if_not__ascii
FROM indata;
-- out  just_ascii_single_byte | nothing_if_not__ascii 
-- out ------------------------+-----------------------
-- out  ZA                     | ZA
```